# String replace within index/MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `MultiIndex`ed DataFrame with codes for countries as follows:

```
In [3]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('AUS', 'a'), ('AUS', 'b'), ('BRA', 'a')])

In [4]: idx.names = ['country', 'foo']
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6], index=idx)
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
             0
country foo   
AUS     a    4
        b    5
BRA     a    6
```

I also have a dictionary with values to replace my codes with:

```
In [7]: codes = dict(AUS='Australia', BRA='Brazil')
```

I'd like to do the equivalent of `df.replace(codes)` but on the index levels (either all levels, or a specific one, I don't mind)

The output would look like:

```
               0
country   foo
Australia a    4
          b    5
Brazil    a    6
```

I'm currently doing it in a very silly way indeed:

```
In [21]: replaced = [pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values(i)).replace(codes) for i in range(len(df.index.levels))]
In [22]: replaced_tuples = zip(*replaced)
In [23]: new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(replaced_tuples)
In [27]: df_replaced = pd.DataFrame(df.values, index=new_idx)
In [28]: df_replaced
Out[28]: 
             0
Australia a  4
          b  5
Brazil    a  6
```

What's the much nicer way that's staring me in the face? (Note that this method doesn't even preserve level names so it's all-round bad.)

Answer (score 3):

You can call `set_levels` on the multi-index and pass the new names, you have to create a list that is the same order as your level names due to dicts not guaranteeing order:

```
In [380]:
country_code_list = [codes[x] for x in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()]
df.index.set_levels(country_code_list, level='country', inplace=True)
df

Out[380]:
               0
country   foo   
Australia a    4
          b    5
Brazil    a    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonable-looking way to do it. Not sure how it compares efficiency/readability-wise against @EdChum's answer:

```
In [46]: df.reset_index().replace(codes).set_index(df.index.names)
Out[46]: 
               0
country   foo   
Australia a    4
          b    5
Brazil    a    6
```

Clearly the downside here is that the `replace` will replace throughout the `DataFrame`, not just in the index columns.

On the upside, doing it this way, you get access to all the functionality of `replace` like regular expressions.

If you really care about *only* replacing within the index you can do either:

```
codes_dict = dict(country=codes)
```

or

```
codes_dict = {k: codes for k in df.index.names}
```

Then finally change `codes` for `codes_dict` in the call to `replace`. Perfect!